# How to dump PostgreSQL database whose owner has no password?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, ubuntu

**First, some background on my setup:**

The server has root access disabled. So, I log-in as (say) `john` who also belongs to the `sudo` group and is therefore able to run superuser commands.

I created a new password-less user<sup>**#1**</sup> `santa` (using the command `sudo adduser --shell /bin/bash --gecos 'Santa Claus' --disabled-password santa`).

Then I changed the login session's owner to `santa` using the command: `sudo su - santa` and created a new PostgreSQL database: `createdb myapp_db` (the database got created without asking me for password).

Now, given the condition, how do I make an SQL dump of the database `myapp_db` (whose owner is `santa`) using the command `pg_dump`?

This is supposed to work, but it isn't:

```
john@host:~$ pg_dump myapp_db -U santa -h localhost --no-owner -W > myapp_db_backup.sql
Password:
```

When I run the above command, it asks me for "password" as you can see. What password am I supposed to enter here? I didn't enter any password for the database when creating it, nor does the database owner `santa` have any.

So, I tried entering the password of `john`, the sudo user, and got this error:

*"FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "santa""*

---

I also tried (which didn't work either):

```
john@host:~$ su - santa
santa@host:~$ pg_dump myapp_db -U santa -h localhost --no-owner -W > myapp_db_backup.sql
Password:
```

This time, I created a password for the user `santa` and entered it. Still get the error:

*"FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "santa""*

What am I missing here?

*(Please let me know if I am missing any necessary details.)*

---

### More Information

(As requested in the comments.)

```
john@host:~$ sudo su postgres
postgres@host:~$ psql -l

                                         List of databases
          Name           |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-------------------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 app_db                  | santa    | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres                | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0               | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
                         |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1               | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
                         |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)
```

Output of `\du santa`:

```
john@host:~$ sudo -u postgres psql
postgres=# \du santa

                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 santa     | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
```

Comment: @dezso When I run `psql -du santa` I get this error: _"psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "santa""_. But this is irrelevant as I am defining hostname in my `pg_dump` command. **Please see my edits, I add a few more details now, which could give you a more clear picture.**

Comment: @dezso Just in case it's unclear what info I added, please see the revisions: http://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/48923/revisions

Comment: @dezso Like I said in an earlier comment, when I run psql -du santa I get this error: _"psql: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "santa""._

Comment: @dezso I am sorry, it was a bit unclear. Anyway, I added the output to my question. Is that exactly what you asked for?

Comment: Yep.  Once you got "FATAL: password authentication failed for user "santa"" and then "psql: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "santa"" - did you change something between the two?

Comment: @dezso I got the _"FATAL: password authentication failed for user "santa""_ error when I ran the `pg_dump` command. And when I ran `psql -du santa` I got the other error, _"psql: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "santa""_. But then I realized you asked me to run `\du santa` command in psql interactively (i.e. after `sudo -u postgres psql`), which gave me the output I posted at the end of the question (please take a look). **No, I didn't change any-thing/config in between.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this part of the `pg_dump` manpage:

> ```
>    -W, --password
>        Force pg_dump to prompt for a password before connecting to a database.
>        This option is never essential, since pg_dump will automatically prompt
>        for a password if the server demands password authentication.
> ```

Don't use `-W` at all. In your case, it's just confusing.

Also, you need to know that the fact that the server asks for a password or not is not driven by the existence  of this password.

It's driven by the server-side [`pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file that you need to study and possibly modify according to your needs (don't forget to reload the server after modifying it).

EDIT: reviewing your pg_hba.conf. The relevant lines are:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

The 1st line concerns the `postgres` user. It's irrelevant for your pg_dump command since you're using the `santa` user with `-U santa`

The 2nd line concerns any other connection through Unix domain sockets (TYPE column is `local`). From the client, it means when you do not use `-h localhost`. It says that if the OS user is the same name than the db user, he doesn't need a password.

The 3rd line says that if `-h localhost` is used (IPv4 TCP connection), a password will always be asked to the client.  The 4th line says the same with IPv6.

Based on this, this command run by the `santa` OS user should not ask or need  a password:

```
 pg_dump --no-owner myapp_db > myapp_db_backup.sql
```

`-U santa` is optional because the db username is taken as the OS user by default.

Comment: also do not use the -h localhost since peer will not work over tcp/ip connections

Comment: Here's the uncommented part of my pg_hba.conf: http://pastebin.com/KfU8YEEV - does that say something? As I see it, I may just have to comment this line: `local   all   postgres   peer` - what do you think?

Comment: @its_me: Originally, what was your need? That the santa user has to enter a password to connect to `myapp_db`, or on the contrary that it should not need a password?

Comment: @DanielVérité that it shouldn't need a password.

Comment: @its_me: edited my answer based on your current pg_hba.conf

Comment: @DanielVérité Thanks for the edit, but actually simply removing the `-W` option like you first suggested solved the problem. :P (I must have missed something earlier.) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer, drop the -h localhost.

With -h localhost it connects over TCP/IP sockets.  Without it, it will connect over UNIX domain sockets.  These are set differently for auth methods in the pg_hba.conf.

So try this:

```bash
john@host:~$ su - santa
santa@host:~$ pg_dump myapp_db -U santa --no-owner -W > myapp_db_backup.sql
```

Comment: I just tried this. It asks me for a password, and there's none! :-/

Comment: If you tried it and it didn't work then either you added a -h localhost or you changed your configuration after creating the database.  You may want to include your pg_hba.conf if that doesn't work after reviewing.